# onDestroy() called when backbutton on actionbar is pressed

Tags: android, android-actionbar, onbackpressed, ondestroy

i have two activities, the first one contains a ListView [image] of hotel list and the second one is a RecyclerView [image: RecyclerView] for displaying the details.

I don't have a problem when i press it using my hardware back button the activity is resumed properly, the ListView still there but i got NullPointerException when i press the back button on the ActionBar and onDestroy() are called.

how to prevent onDestroy() called when i click the back button on action bar?

**EDIT:** 
this is the logcat of lifecycle :
1. SearchResult init()

```
11-21 14:36:45.872 3037-3037/com.agranirwa.travel E/ActivityState: In the onStart() event
11-21 14:36:45.882 3037-3037/com.agranirwa.travel E/ActivityState: In the onResume() event
```

2. When ListView item choosed

```
11-21 14:37:55.922 3037-3037/com.agranirwa.travel E/ActivityState: In the onPause() event
11-21 14:37:56.602 3037-3037/com.agranirwa.travel E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
11-21 14:37:56.732 3037-3037/com.agranirwa.travel E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
11-21 14:37:56.982 3037-3037/com.agranirwa.travel E/ActivityState: In the onStop() event
```

3. When hardware backpressed

```
11-21 14:38:14.562 3037-3037/com.agranirwa.travel E/ActivityState: In the onRestart() event
11-21 14:38:14.562 3037-3037/com.agranirwa.travel E/ActivityState: In the onStart() event
11-21 14:38:14.562 3037-3037/com.agranirwa.travel E/ActivityState: In the onResume() event
```

4. When actionbar backpressed

```
11-21 14:40:15.052 3037-3037/com.agranirwa.travel E/ActivityState: Activity is Finished
11-21 14:40:15.052 3037-3037/com.agranirwa.travel E/ActivityState: In the onDestroy() event
11-21 14:40:15.112 3037-3037/com.agranirwa.travel E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.agranirwa.travel, PID: 3037
                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.agranirwa.travel/com.agranirwa.travel.ui.SearchResultActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                        at com.agranirwa.travel.ui.SearchResultActivity.onCreate(SearchResultActivity.java:100)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612) 
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: In the first, you have to read [android activity life-cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html).
onDestroy() method called every time activity finished, so you can't prevent to call it, but you can override this method.

post your code and your logcat error.

Comment: @FarshidABZ : wait, i will show the logcat

Comment: And what is your android version?

Comment: @FarshidABZ : i'm using android KitKat 4.4.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your back button in ActionBar has some problem, you should really add your actual code  or implement this solution

Add after initializing the ActionBar

```
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

and then add the following

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)
{       
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, post onclick listener to your back button in actionBar, not the pictures , code